# Error on using find function on map

Tags: c++

I am defining map using my own class A as the data value for the key of map. I am also using find() function of the map. But I am getting the error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
using namespace std;
class A{
    public:
        int x;
        A(int a){
            x=a;
        }

};
int main(){
    map<int,A> m;
    m[0]=A(3);
    m[1]=A(5);
    m[2]=A(6);
    if(m.find(3) == m.end())
        cout<<"none"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"done"<<endl;
}
```

Error

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/map:61:0,
                 from temp.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_map.h: In member function ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = int, _Tp = A, _Compare = std::less<int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, A> >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = A, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = int]’:
temp.cpp:14:5:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_map.h:453:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_map.h:453:11: note: candidates are:
temp.cpp:7:3: note: A::A(int)
temp.cpp:7:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
temp.cpp:4:7: note: A::A(const A&)
temp.cpp:4:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the [operator[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator[]/) to access the map, the documentation says:

> If k does not match the key of any element in the container, the
>   function inserts a new element with that key and returns a reference
>   to its mapped value. Notice that this always increases the container
>   size by one, even if no mapped value is assigned to the element (the
>   element is constructed using its default constructor).

thus you need a default constructor if you intend to use it: that operator needs it to return a reference to the newly default-constructed and inserted element.

Otherwise you can do this:

```
m.insert(std::pair<int,A>(0,A(3)));
```

which doesn't need a default constructor available.

Comment: Using [map::insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/) is also an option, if the OP has strong feelings about default constructors

Comment: @Jason I already updated the question, thanks by the way

Comment: What if I want to get the value. e.g. A a= m[0] ?

Comment: @user3747190 Use `A a = m.find( 0 )->second;`